# Unary predicate with member function

Tags: c++, algorithm, unary-function

I would like to use a unary function to look up a certain parameter name in a list with std::find

```
class Parameter {
    public:
        string getName() { return mName;}
        //string mName;
    private:
        string mName;
        string mType;
        string mValue;
    };

    class Param_eq : public unary_function<Parameter, bool> {
        string mName;
    public: 
        Param_eq (const string& name) : mName(name) {}
        bool operator() (const Parameter& par) const { 
            return (mName == par.getName());
        }
    };

    double Config::getDouble(string& name) {
        list<Parameter>::iterator iParam = find(mParamList.begin(), mParamList.end(), Param_eq(name));
        double para = iParam->getDouble();
        return para;
    }
}
```

But I get the following compiler error

```
error C2662: 'Parameter::getName' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Parameter' to 'Parameter &'
Conversion loses qualifiers
```

If I make the member variable Parameter::mName public and use it instead of the member function Parameter::getName() in the return statement of Param_eq::operator() it compiles without error.

```
bool operator() (const Parameter& par) const { 
    return (mName == par.mName);
}
```

Why is that? Both member variable and member function are string type.

How do I get the above example to work by using a member function?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: `string getName() const { return mName;}` You have `Param_eq` take a const `Parameter`, but say that `getName` may modify the object it's called on. That's what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you that you are calling a non-const method on a const reference. A non-const method may modify member variables and thus violate the const constraint.

You can solve this two ways:

1. Don't call the method at all and access the `mName` variable directly:

   ```
   bool operator() (const Parameter& par) const { 
       return (mName == par.mName);
   }
   ```

   Note that this does not require making `mName` public. This works because `operator()` is a member of the `Parameter` class. Remember that private members are accessible in any method of the class. It does not matter whether you access the private members of another instance of the same class or not.
2. Declare `getName()` to be `const` objects:

   ```
   string getName() const { return mName;}
   ```

   Note the location of the `const` qualifier. This tells the compiler that the method will not modify any member variables.

Comment: It would also make sense to return a `const string &` to avoid spawning temporaries and to make getter non throwing.

Comment: @VTT good point. Although not directly related to the error which the OP is asking about.

Comment: @VTT generally, a `const` method should not return a reference (`const` or otherwise) to internal data. Returning by value is preferred.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice declaring `getName()` to be `const` solves the problem, however, trying to access the private `Parameter::mName` in `Parameter_eq::operator()` does not work and generates compile error 'cannot access private member'. But still, problem resoved, thanks!